# Typescript emits different output on different machines (VS Code)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I develop my project on two machines, home and office. Each time I switch, the output (.js, .js.map) changes. Tsc on one machine emits the following line, the other doesn't.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Both machines use typescript 2.2.2., same version of code, same tsconfig targeting es5/commonjs (it's part of the repo), no ts related prefs in the user settings of VS Code... I'm stumped. TIA

Comment: Can you check that the `tsc` version on your `path` is the same between both machines: `tsc --version`

Comment: Sure, I did that. In any case, I doubt the tsc version is a factor, since the extra code line (quoted in the question) seems related to the target module system, not the basic transpiling.